# How to use update method of an observer to update different labels?

Tags: java, codenameone

I am trying to create a scoreview with different labels and update each once the a variable state changes. So say I have this class which extends observable and it has severable methods that change the values of live, clock, food, and health. These methods also notify the observers which in my case is the scoreview.

```
import java.util.Observable;

import com.codename1.ui.Display;    
public class GameWorld extends Observable { 
            .....
            private int lives = 3; 
            private int clock = 10; 
            private int food = 0;
            private int health = 0;
            .....

            public void someMethodThatChangesValueOfLives {
                    lives--; //decreases lives
                    setChanged();
                    notifyObservers(lives);  
            }
            public void someMethodThatChangesValueOfClock {
                    clock++; //increases clock
                    setChanged();
                    notifyObservers(clock);  
            }
            public void someMethodThatChangesValueOfFood {
                    food += 30; //decreases lives
                    setChanged();
                    notifyObservers(food);  
            }
            public void someMethodThatChangesValueOfHealth {
                    health += 30; //decreases lives
                    setChanged();
                    notifyObservers(health);  
            }
    }
```

My scoreview class has different labels which store the curent lives, clock, food, and health. My problem is How am I suppose to tell the update method which label to update? Say my lives decrease how do I make it update the lives label instead of the clock label or other labels?

```
import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;
import com.codename1.ui.Container;
import com.codename1.ui.Label;

    public class ScoreView extends Container implements Observer {
        private Label timeLabelText;
        private Label timeLabelValue;
        private Label livesLabelText;
        private Label livesLabelValue;
        private Label foodLabelText;
        private Label foodLabelValue;
        private Label healthLabelText;
        private Label healthLabelValue;
        ...more labels

        public ScoreView () {
            timeLabelText = new Label("Time:");
            timeLabelValue = new Label(" 0");
            livesLabelText = new Label("Lives Left:");
            livesLabelValue = new Label(" 3");
            foodLabelText = new Label("Food Level:");
            foodLabelValue = new Label("30");
            healthLabelText = new Label("Health Level:");
            healthLabelValue = new Label("10");
            ...more labels

            this.addComponent(timeLabelText);
            this.addComponent(timeLabelValue);
            ...add more labels to components
        }

        //How to tell update which label to update from the argument?
        public void update (Observable o, Object arg) {
            String clock = (String)arg;
            timeLabelValue.setText(clock);
            String lives = (String)arg;
            livesLabelValue.setText(lives);
            String food = (String)arg;
            foodLabelValue.setText(food);
            String health = (String)arg;
            healthLabelValue.setText(health);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Properties work great for this, and they have several other convenience features as well.

https://www.codenameone.com/blog/tutorial-properties.html

Comment: Agreed. There is also `EventDispatcher` which allows you to add listeners and fire events to them